# How do I add an animation to another element when another div class is hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

For example, if I have an element that is not wrapped within the same parent container as another div I am hovering,  will it be possible to change this external element style?

```
<div class="externalElement"></div>


    <container>
    
    <div class="tohover"></div> </container>
```

How can I update

"externalElement" when I hover "tohover" div class? I've tried with jQuery but to no avail..

Comment: Using jQuery it is possible

Comment: how do i do so?

Comment: I have added an answer with snippet, can you check?

Comment: If that other element is a child or sibling of your hover element you can do it using CSS selectors... Otherwise Using JavaScript.. if you insist using CSS wait until css4 specifications available to select any element you wish..

Comment: @bugbytes check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68561091/12860895), it is a vanilla JavaScript no jQuery answer and is a lot simpler

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript answer.

Hover on the blue box to make the red box green.

[`onmouseover` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseover):

> The `onmouseover` property of the [`GlobalEventHandlers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) mixin is an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers) that processes [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) events.
>
> The `mouseover` event fires when the user moves the mouse over a particular element.

[`onmouseout` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseout):

> The `onmouseout` property of the [`GlobalEventHandlers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) mixin is an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers) that processes [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) events.

> The `mouseout` event fires when the mouse leaves an element. For example, when the mouse moves off of an image in the web page, the `mouseout` event is raised for that image element.

```js
const $externalElement = document.querySelector('.externalElement')
const $tohover = document.querySelector('.tohover')

$tohover.onmouseover = () => {
  $externalElement.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen'
}

$tohover.onmouseout = () => {
  $externalElement.style.backgroundColor = 'indianred'
}
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

.externalElement {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: indianred;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.tohover {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: steelblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <container>
    <div class="tohover">Hover me!</div>
  </container>

  <div class="externalElement"></div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `mouseover` and `mouseout` functionalities, you can achieve this as below;

```js
$('.tohover').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('.externalElement').addClass('hovered')
})

$('.tohover').on('mouseout', function() {
  $('.externalElement').removeClass('hovered')
})
```

```css
.tohover {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.externalElement {
  color: red;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.externalElement.hovered {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="externalElement">Here</div>


<div>
  <div class="tohover">Hover me!</div>
</div>
```

I used the `mouseover` and `mouseout` so that it will be easy to understand. Otherwise,it can be achieved using a single function.

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 different options the first is to use the sibling selector and just go pretty specific, what I wouldn't recommend because of selector sepcifity. The second option would be using jQuery as shown in the exmaple below.

The hover function accepts 2 parameters, one is what will happen on enter, the other is what happens on leave.

I also added a solution without jquery and plain js.

```js
$('.hover').hover(
  () => $('.far').addClass('hovered'), 
  () => $('.far').removeClass('hovered')
)


const target = document.querySelector('.far-nonjquery');
const hover = document.querySelector('.hover')
hover.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => target.classList.add('hovered'));
hover.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => target.classList.remove('hovered'));
```

```css
.hover:hover + .next {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.hovered {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover">Hover</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>


<div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span class="far">Far away</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span class="far-nonjquery">Far away non jquery</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ancestor cannot be selected in CSS. But in your example you are selecting the sibling.

Comment: As per the question, the element needs to be hovered is the one inside the container. Not the target one

Comment: @AbinThaha, okay? Doesn't make a difference tho with the jquery solution. When I started coding there was no code or anything in the initial question :)

Comment: Ok, but it was mentioned in the question that he used the jQuery to achieve it but failed. So that I used jQuery as there are no way of achieving this using CSS only. Using jQuery or JavaScript would work for a solution.